# OxyPlot PlotView in User Control does not work WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, controls, oxyplot

I added PlotView to User Control. Then I added this User Control to the form. When I run program nothing is shown on the form (neither in tableLayoutPanel neither on Panel neither directly on Form. I added PlotView directly on Form without User Control and it works. But I want to make it via User Control. What the reason could it be? I found some issues about WPF and tableLayoutPanel problems. But as I said I use Windows Forms and I tried place User Control directly on the Form

Comment: Do you do it in the designer or in code?

Comment: TaW, I compile Project with User Control and add this control in the designer from toolbox

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in incorrect usage of UserControl. I tried reinitialize it with parameter constructor. So I have to make initialization in some  public method which is called by form. So the problem was not in OxyPlot but in my wrong usage of UserControl